# Задача на rxJava

Tags: rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

У нас есть `Observable<Int>` который эммитит разные числа. Нам надо встать между Observable и подписчиком и смотреть когда к нам в `onNext` приходит число "x" то мы увеличиваем счетчик на единицу и если счетчик становится == 3, то выбрасываем исключение, когда же нам приходит число "y" то мы обнуляем счетчик. Как это реализовать только с использованием rx?

Comment: Задача не интересная, она примитивная и выглядит как костыль. Для чего это?

Comment: какая разница для чего? Если не можешь предложить решения, то зачем вообще что-то тут писать?

Comment: Разница есть, почитайте про "[проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/204271)".

Answer (score 0):

Написал простой пример. Вот класс, который эммитит числа.

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable

class IntRepository {
    fun getIntegers() = Observable.just(5, 5, 10, 0, 5, 2, 10, 4)
}
```

Далее класс прослойка между observable и подписчиком.

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable

class Layer(
    private val intRepository: IntRepository
) {
    private val x = 5
    private val y = 10
    private var counter = 0

    fun lookOn(): Observable<Int> {
        return intRepository.getIntegers().map {
            if (it == x) {
                counter++
                if (counter == 3) {
                    throw Exception("Counter equals 3")
                }
            } else if (it == y) {
                counter = 0
            }
            return@map it
        }
    }
}
```

И наконец класс MainActivity с подписчиком.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observer
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers
import timber.log.Timber

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var layer: Layer

    private lateinit var observer: Observer<Int>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        layer = Layer(IntRepository())

        observer = object : Observer<Int> {

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {
                Timber.i("onSubscribe")
            }

            override fun onNext(t: Int?) {
                Timber.i("onNext: $t")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                Timber.e("Error: ${e?.message}")
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                Timber.i("onComplete")
            }
        }

        layer.lookOn()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(observer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Такой вариант я и сам могу написать. В задаче написано же, что с использованием только rx. В вашем же случае создаются переменные за пределами rx цепочки, что не допустимо по условиям.